# conditionally highlighting cells based on statistical significance using kableExtra

Tags: r, dplyr, kable, kableextra

Say I have this tibble:

```
d <- tibble::tribble(
             ~dimension, ~albania, ~georgia, ~croatia, ~slovakia, ~czechia,  ~albania_stat_sig, ~georgia_stat_sig,  ~croatia_stat_sig, ~slovakia_stat_sig,  ~czechia_stat_sig,
              "beaches",       1L,       3L,       4L,        6L,       4L,  "positive, small",  "positive_large",  "positive, small", "positive, medium",        "no change",
                "coast",       5L,       1L,       4L,        2L,       2L,        "no change", "positive_medium",  "positive, large",  "positive, small",        "no change",
               "forest",       2L,       2L,       2L,        5L,       1L,  "positive, small",       "no change", "negative, medium",  "positive, small", "positive, medium",
       "cost of living",       1L,       7L,       3L,        8L,       5L, "positive, medium",       "no change",        "no change", "positive, medium",  "positive, small",
        "public safety",       6L,       9L,       1L,        2L,       7L,  "negative, large", "negative, small",        "no change",  "negative, large",  "negative, small"
       )
```

I want to take columns d[1:6] and all rows and turn this into a table that highlights each cell in the country columns based on the value in the corresponding `_stat_sig` column for the same country.

This is what i've tried so far:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)

d[1:5, 1:6] %>%
    kbl() %>%
    kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
    column_spec(1:6, color = "white",
                background = spec_color(d[1:5, 7:11], end = 0.7))
```

But I am getting the error message:

```
Error in UseMethod("rescale") : 
  no applicable method for 'rescale' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl', 'data.frame')"
```

I would end up with a table that looks something like this:

[image]

So, when the cell in the country_`_stat_sig` column is 'negative' the corresponding cell for that row and country, it is one of three shades of red (where a deeper shade of red is for 'negative, large' and a lighter shade of red for 'negative, small'); and when the country_`_stat_sig` column is 'positive' the corresponding cell in the country column is one of three shades of green.

Can anyone help me out here? Would be immensely grateful for any pointers!

**Edit to question:**

As you can see in the example image above, I also want the numbers to be white for the two deepest shades of red and green, but to remain black/whatever the default is for the lightest shades of red and green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to use `purrr::reduce` or `Reduce` to assign the background colors to each column separately like so:

```
library(kableExtra)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

pal_color <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x %in% "positive, small" ~ "#9AFF9A",
    x %in% c("positive_medium", "positive, medium") ~ "#7CCD7C",
    x %in% c("positive_large", "positive, large") ~ "#548B54",
    x %in% "negative, small" ~ "#FF6A6A",
    x %in% c("negative, medium") ~ "#CD5555",
    x %in% c("negative, large") ~ "#8B3A3A",
    TRUE ~ "white"
  )
}

pal_textcolor <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x %in% c("positive_medium", "positive, medium") ~ "white",
    x %in% c("positive_large", "positive, large") ~ "white",
    x %in% c("negative, large") ~ "white",
    TRUE ~ "black"
  )
}

d %>%
  select(1:6) %>%
  kbl() %>%
  kable_paper(full_width = F) %>%
  purrr::reduce(
    2:6, function(.x, .y) {
      col <- names(d)[[.y]]
      column_spec(.x, .y,
                  background = pal_color(d[[paste0(col, "_stat_sig")]]),
                  color = pal_textcolor(d[[paste0(col, "_stat_sig")]])
      )  
    },
    .init = .
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! It looks like exactly what I want. I'm getting an error though for `case_match`: `Error in case_match(x, "positive, small" ~ "#9AFF9A", c("positive_medium", : could not find function "case_match"`

Comment: Oh yeah. Check your dplyr version. `case_match` was introduced with `dplyr 1.1.0` some weeks ago. Of course could we do the same with `case_when` but it's a bit more verbose.

Comment: I just re-installed `dplyr` and according to `packageVersion('dplyr')` I am running `1.1.0`. I've even tried to specifically tell R `case_match` comes from `dplyr` by writing `dplyr::case_match(...)` but i am still getting an error: `Error: 'case_match' is not an exported object from 'namespace:dplyr'`

Comment: So with `case_when` I can just put `x == ` before each line of the case_when statement. That's working for me! Thank you again. Do you have any thoughts on how I can make the text white for only the two darkest shades of red and green (but keep it black for the lightest shade)?

Comment: I just added the `case_when` version as an edit.

Comment: Awesome. I've also just edited the question to make the point about making the text white for some cells clearer

Comment: See my edit. First I added the text colors. Second, in your example data .y + 5 is the position of the `_stat_sig` column, i.e. if .y = 2 (albania) it will return 7 (albania_stat_sig). But right, as we are using positions it is error prone. In the edit I fixed that. Now I use the column name, i.e. `col <- names(d)[[.y]]` will give us the column name and `d[[paste0(col, "_stat_sig")]]` the corresponding stat_sig column.

Comment: I'm struggling with getting this to work with my actual data. Say there is an extra column in position `1` that I don't want/need. I've changed the `select` to read `select(2:7)` and then `purrr::reduce(3:7, ... )` but now I get the error: `Error in xml_children(x)[[search]] : subscript out of bounds`. I think I just don't fully understand what the .x, .y and positions are doing in this function so it's hard for me to adapt it. Would appreciate any guidance you can offer here!

Comment: (: When you do `select(2:7)` the second column becomes the first and so on, i.e. you still could go on with `reduce(2:6, ...)`.

Comment: :P So, trying that I now get this error: `Error in if (substr(color, 1, 1) != "#" | nchar(color) != 9) return(color) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In ensure_len_html(color, nrows, "color") :
  The number of provided values in color does not equal to the number of rows. 
2: In ensure_len_html(background, nrows, "background") :
  The number of provided values in background does not equal to the number of rows.`